# 'Un'-externalize strings from Eclipse or Intellij

Tags: java, internationalization, externalizing

I have a bunch of strings in a properties file which i want to 'un-externalize', ie inline into my code.

I see that both Eclipse and Intellij have great support to 'externalize' strings from within code, however do any of them support inlining strings from a properties file back into code?

For example if I have code like -

**My.java**

```
System.out.println(myResourceBundle.getString("key"));
```

**My.properties**

```
key=a whole bunch of text
```

I want my java code to be replaced as -

**My.java**

```
System.out.println("a whole bunch of text");
```

Comment: Could you explain, what should it be good for? According to your comment, you may want speed, but isn't the map lookup time negligible as compared to the string output?

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a simple java program that you can use to do this.

### Dexternalize.java

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class Deexternalize {

    public static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Deexternalize.class.toString());

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        if(args.length != 2) {
            System.out.println("Deexternalize props_file java_file_to_create");
            return;
        }

        Properties defaultProps = new Properties();
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
        defaultProps.load(in);
        in.close();

        File javaFile = new File(args[1]);

        List<String> data = process(defaultProps,javaFile);

        buildFile(javaFile,data);

    }

    public static List<String> process(Properties propsFile, File javaFile) {
        List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
        Set<Entry<Object,Object>> setOfProps = propsFile.entrySet();
        int indexOf = javaFile.getName().indexOf(".");
        String javaClassName = javaFile.getName().substring(0,indexOf);

        data.add("public class " + javaClassName + " {\n");
        StringBuilder sb = null;

        // for some reason it's adding them in reverse order so putting htem on a stack
        Stack<String> aStack = new Stack<String>();

        for(Entry<Object,Object> anEntry : setOfProps) {
            sb = new StringBuilder("\tpublic static final String ");
            sb.append(anEntry.getKey().toString());
            sb.append(" = \"");
            sb.append(anEntry.getValue().toString());
            sb.append("\";\n");
            aStack.push(sb.toString());
        }

        while(!aStack.empty()) {
            data.add(aStack.pop());
        }

        if(sb != null) {
            data.add("}");
        }

        return data;
    }

    public static final void buildFile(File fileToBuild, List<String> lines) {
        BufferedWriter theWriter = null;

        try {
            // Check to make sure if the file exists already.
            if(!fileToBuild.exists()) {
                fileToBuild.createNewFile();
            }

            theWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileToBuild));

            // Write the lines to the file.
            for(String theLine : lines) {
                // DO NOT ADD windows carriage return.
                if(theLine.endsWith("\r\n")){
                    theWriter.write(theLine.substring(0, theLine.length()-2));
                    theWriter.write("\n");
                } else if(theLine.endsWith("\n")) {
                    // This case is UNIX format already since we checked for
                    // the carriage return already.
                    theWriter.write(theLine);
                } else {
                    theWriter.write(theLine);
                    theWriter.write("\n");
                }
            }

        } catch(IOException ex) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                theWriter.close();
            } catch(IOException ex) {
                logger.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, all you need to do is call this java program with the location of the property file and the name of the java file you want to create that will contain the properties.

For instance this property file:

### test.properties

```
TEST_1=test test test
TEST_2=test 2456
TEST_3=123456
```

will become:

### java_test.java

```
public class java_test {
    public static final String TEST_1 = "test test test";
    public static final String TEST_2 = "test 2456";
    public static final String TEST_3 = "123456";
}
```

Hope this is what you need!

EDIT:

I understand what you requested now.  You can use my code to do what you want if you sprinkle a bit of regex magic.  Lets say you have the java_test file from above.  Copy the inlined properties into the file you want to replace the myResourceBundle code with.

For example,

### TestFile.java

```
public class TestFile {

    public static final String TEST_1 = "test test test";
    public static final String TEST_2 = "test 2456";
    public static final String TEST_3 = "123456";

    public static void regexTest() {

        System.out.println(myResourceBundle.getString("TEST_1"));
        System.out.println(myResourceBundle.getString("TEST_1"));
        System.out.println(myResourceBundle.getString("TEST_3"));

    }
}
```

Ok, now if you are using eclipse (any modern IDE should be able to do this) go to the Edit Menu -> Find/Replace.  In the window, you should see a "Regular Expressions" checkbox, check that.  Now input the following text into the Find text area:

```
myResourceBundle\.getString\(\"(.+)\"\)
```

And the back reference

```
\1
```

into the replace.

Now click "Replace all"  and voila! The code should have been inlined to your needs.

Now TestFile.java will become:

### TestFile.java

```
public class TestFile {

    public static final String TEST_1 = "test test test";
    public static final String TEST_2 = "test 2456";
    public static final String TEST_3 = "123456";

    public static void regexTest() {

        System.out.println(TEST_1);
        System.out.println(TEST_1);
        System.out.println(TEST_3);

    }
}
```

Comment: This should be a good start for you here at StackOverflow :).

Comment: Thanks! This could be extended to detect if the value is int or double etc but I felt that String was the most commonly used property, plus I only had about half an hour of boredom to fix. :)

Comment: dont see how this helps at all. Your code converts a properties file to a java file. That is not what I need. I have a java code with references in string to keys in a property file which need to be inlined. This does not solve that problem at all.

Comment: pdeva, this code answers your question, "I have a bunch of strings in a properties file which i want to 'un-externalize', ie inline into my code".  You need to be more specific in your question.

Comment: you dont understand what inlining means.i didnt ask for a property file to java code convertor.

Comment: Hi pdeva:  I updated the answer to reflect the changes to the question.  Hopefully this will address what you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You may use Eclipse "Externalize Strings" widget. It can also be used for un-externalization. Select required string(s) and press "Internalize" button. If the string was externalized before, it'll be put back and removed from messages.properties file.

Comment: While somewhat cumbersome, this is definitely the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

May be if you can explain on how you need to do this, then  you could get the correct answer.

The Short answer to your question is no, especially in Intellij (I do not know enough about eclipse). Of course the slightly longer but still not very useful answer is to write a plugin. ( That will take a list of property files and read the key and values in a map and then does a regular expression replace of ResourceBundle.getValue("Key") with the value from Map (for the key).  I will write this plugin myself, if you can convince me that, there are more people like you, who have this requirement.)

The more elaborate answer is this.

1_ First I will re-factor all the code that performs property file reading to a single class (or module called PropertyFileReader).

2_ I will create a property file reader module, that iterates across all the keys in property file(s) and then stores those information in a map.

4_ I can either create a static map objects with the populated values or create a constant class out of it. Then I will replace the logic in the property file reader module to use a get on the map or static class rather than the property file reading.

5_ Once I am sure that the application performs ok.(By checking if all my Unit Testing passes), then I will remove my property files.

Note: If you are using spring, then there is a easy way to split out all property key-value pairs from a list of property files. Let me know if you use spring.

Comment: in the case you described the strings will still be in a map which will have to be looked up each time. I am looking for a full inline which just puts the string right in the code.

Comment: What about writing your own plug in. What operating system are you in. What you are looking at is batch find and replace. Printout the contents of map and use some file  utility  to find and replace in batch.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend something else: split externalized strings into localizable and non-localizable properties files. It would be probably easier to move some strings to another file than moving it back to source code (which will hurt maintainability by the way).

Of course you can write simple (to some extent) Perl (or whatever) script which will search for calls to resource bundles and introduce constant in this place... 
In other words, I haven't heard about de-externalizing mechanism, you need to do it by hand (or write some automated script yourself).

Answer (score 0):

An awesome oneliner from @potong `sed 's|^\([^=]*\)=\(.*\)|s@Messages.getString("\1")@"\2"@g|;s/\\/\\\\/g' messages.properties |
sed -i -f - *.java` run this inside your src dir, and see the magic.