# sed script won't work with some entries

Tags: linux, sed

I have a file called `messages.properties` which has lines with syntax `<key>=<string>`. Each `key` is unique but `string` isn't. Many keys can have a same string.  Also in the same folder I have some java classes which read the strings from `messages.properties`. They get string via the method `Messages.getString("<key>")`. So what I need to do is to convert `Messages.getString("<key>")` in java classes into `"<key>"` by reading their value from `messages.properties`. Here's the sed onliner from @potong that does the trick.

```
sed 's|^\([^=]*\)=\(.*\)|s@Messages.getString("\1")@"\2"@g|;s/\\/\\\\/g' messages.properties |
sed -i -f - *.java
```

However the issue with this is it won't work for some in `messages.properties`. How should I modify the script to solve this? Here's a related question [Search and replace with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10002904/1068546)  .

Sample messages.properties

```
Sting.1=Str
Sting.2=String
Sting.3=String
Sting.4=Strring
Sting.5=Str
```

Sample java class

```
System.Out.println(Messages.getString("Sting.1"));
System.Out.println(Messages.getString("Sting.2"));
System.Out.println(Messages.getString("Sting.3"));
System.Out.println(Messages.getString("Sting.4"));
System.Out.println(Messages.getString("Sting.5"));
```

Reqired java class

```
System.Out.println("Str");
System.Out.println("String");
System.Out.println("String");
System.Out.println("Strring");
System.Out.println("Str");
```

Comment: please consider updating your question with a sample properties file with 3 entries (or the bare minimum to illustrate the problem) and your required output from that same data. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter I will add it, but meanwhile you can check the link for samples.

Comment: hm... 2 things, don't see either VSDataSource.89 or VSDataSource.90 in your properties sample. 2. please show us the output you are getting for the above block. How do you mean 'won't work when the <string> is repeated in messages.properties'? I guess I'm saying, it would be helpful to see exact inputs, exact and required outputs for same inputs that produce errors. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter edited the question accordingly

Comment: @potong Please help me with this.

Comment: I've never heard of that before :-!   Just to help us small-timers out, please update your question to include those file sizes. Thanks and good luck.

Comment: @I was actally mistook, it was not a problem with sizes either. the actual problem was that eclipse split `Messages.getString("Sting.3")` into 2 lines, `Messages` and `.getString("Sting.3")`. So `sed 's|^\([^=]*\)=\(.*\)|s@.getString("\1")@"\2"@g|;s/\\/\\\\/g' messages.properties |
sed -i -f - *.java` worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem was that eclipse split

```
Messages.getString("String.3")
```

into 2 lines,

```
    Messages
        .getString("String.3")
```

So this worked.

```
sed 's|^\([^=]*\)=\(.*\)|s@.getString("\1")@"\2"@g|;s/\\/\\\\/g' messages.properties |
sed -i -f - *.java
```

Comment: Well done for spotting problem and fixing up the solution!. A word of caution though, beware of false positives the more you shorten the search string.